# using nodemon to watch bash script file changes

Tags: bash, vim, nodemon

I'm using `nodemon` to re-run shell script on save:

```
nodemon --exec "./hello.sh || exit 1" -e sh
```

But it crashes on save :

```
sh: 1: ./hello.sh: Text file busy
```

It happens when using `vim`, it's working using `nano` editor , well.
It seems the filesystem busy by `vim`. Any solution?

Comment: How are you making the changes to the script? Through Visual Studio?

Comment: @RamanSailopal ```vim```

Comment: Oh it seems it's working using ```nano```

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure that you have fully exited the file and no other process is holding it.

Comment: It works fine, here. Can you try with `$ vim -Nu NONE hello.sh`? (Also, I highly recommend the dependency-free [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/) instead of nodemon.)